# how to use cache in cakePHP3

Tags: caching, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

I am trying to use cache in cakePHP3 to store query results.

I declared a cache adapter named "bl"

config/app.php :

```
/**
 * Configure the cache adapters.
 */
'Cache' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'File',
        'path' => CACHE,
        'url' => env('CACHE_DEFAULT_URL', null),
    ],

    'bl' => [
        'className' => 'File',
        'path' => CACHE . 'bl/',
        'url' => env('CACHE_DEFAULT_URL', null),
        'duration' => '+1 week',

    ],
```

src/Controller/UsersController.php :

```
use Cake\Cache\Cache;
...
        public function test()
        {
                $this->autoRender = false;
                $this->loadModel('Users');
                $Users = $this->Users->find('all');
                $Users->cache('test', 'bl');
                debug(Cache::read('test', 'bl'));
        }
```

The debug return "false".

tmp/cache/bl/ directory were well created, but no cache files were generated.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: I tried this code    `public function test()
    {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $users = $this->Users->find('all')->toArray();
        $users->cache('test_cache', 'bl');
        //Cache::write('test_cache', $users, 'bl');
        debug(Cache::read('test_cache', 'bl'));
    }
` Cache looks waiting on an object not en array : `Error: Call to a member function cache() on array
File /opt/myapp/src/Controller/UsersController.php
Line: 43 `

Answer (score 1):

Your query is never being executed, hence it's never going to be cached. Run the query by invoking `all()`, or `toArray()`, or by iterating over it, etc...

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > How Are Queries Lazily Evaluated](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#how-are-queries-lazily-evaluated)**

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the proper method, you need to use Cache::write() not Users->cache(). I updated your code below:

```
use Cake\Cache\Cache;
...
        public function test()
        {
                $this->autoRender = false;
                $this->loadModel('Users');
                $Users = $this->Users->find('all');
                Cache::write('cache_key_name', $Users, 'bl');
                debug(Cache::read('cache_key_name', 'bl'));
        }
```

See https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#writing-to-a-cache

Comment: I tried your code, but I am getting this error  :

`Error: You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances

If you are using SQL keywords as table column names, you can enable identifier quoting for your database connection in config/app.php.

If you want to customize this error message, create src/Template/Error/pdo_error.ctp`

Comment: My answer is correct and answers your cache question. See ndm's response for your other issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution with your 2 answers, the final code is :

```
public function test()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $users = $this->Users->find('all')->toArray();
    Cache::write('test_cache', $users, 'bl');
    debug(Cache::read('test_cache', 'bl'));
}
```